# How to get get Previous Day 11:00 AM Open Price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am new to pine script kindly please advice me a code snip , How to get get Previous Day 11:00 AM Open Price

I would like to write a strategy based on this price level, below code is not working properly for each day

```
t = timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow)-1, 11, 0)  // 1st of November 2017
l = float(na)

var oprice = 0
if time >= t and na(l[1])
    l := open
    oprice = l
    l
else
    l := l[1]
    l

plot(l)
```

Comment: On what timeframe are you going to be using this?

Comment: 5 minute timeframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bar exists, you can easily do that by using the `hour` and `minute` built-in variables.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

is_11_am = (hour == 11) and (minute == 0)

bgcolor(is_11_am ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)

var float open_11_am_today = na
var float open_11_am_yesterday = na

if (is_11_am)
    open_11_am_yesterday := open_11_am_today
    open_11_am_today := open

plot(open_11_am_yesterday, color=color.red)
plot(open_11_am_today, color=color.green)
```

[image]